# Does Python have a conditional NOT statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-expression

I'd like to filter a list of values. Depending on the state of a variable, I'd like to return the positive or negative result of the filter. Example:

```
def foo(it, my_condition):
    return [s for s in it if (s.startswith("q") if my_condition else not s.startswith("q"))]

foo(["The", "quick", "brown", "fox"], my_condition=True)
```

So on `my_condition=True` I get `["quick"]` and on `my_condition=False` I get `["The", "brown", "fox"]`.

What I don't like about the implementation is this part: `(s.startswith("q") if filter else not s.startswith("q"))`. It contains duplicate code and takes up a lot of space in an otherwise concise list comprehension. What I really want is just to insert a `not` after the `if`, depending on the state of the `filter` variable.

Is there a more pretty / clean solution to this? If possible, I'd like to avoid the computational overhead of lambda expressions in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just compare the result of `startswith` with the boolean parameter:

```
def foo(it, keep_matches):
    return [s for s in it if s.startswith("q") == keep_matches]
```

note: don't call your variable `filter` as this is a built-in function to filter iterables, I changed for a more explicit name (not sure it's the best choice, but it's better than `flag` or `filter`)

Comment: As `startswith` is returning a boolean shouldn't the comparison better be `s.startswith("q") is flag`? Anyway good answer.

Comment: yes, `True` and `False` are singletons so that would work. But by experience I tend to avoid `is` because it brings little benefits and a lot of problems.